# AvroInputFormat returns set of object addresses instead of values

Tags: scala, apache-flink, avro, flink-batch

I'm writing some data using flink AvroOutputFormat,

```
val source: DataSet[Row] = environment.createInput(inputBuilder.finish)
val tableEnv: BatchTableEnvironment = new BatchTableEnvironment(environment, TableConfig.DEFAULT)
val table: Table = source.toTable(tableEnv)
val avroOutputFormat = new AvroOutputFormat[Row](classOf[Row])
avroOutputFormat.setCodec(AvroOutputFormat.Codec.NULL)
source.write(avroOutputFormat, "/Users/x/Documents/test_1.avro").setParallelism(1)
environment.execute()
```

This writes data into a file called `test_1.avro`. When I tried to read the file as,

```
val users = new AvroInputFormat[Row](new Path("/Users/x/Documents/test_1.avro"), classOf[Row])
val usersDS = environment.createInput(users)
usersDS.print()
```

This prints the row as,

```
java.lang.Object@4462efe1,java.lang.Object@7c3e4b1a,java.lang.Object@2db4ad1,java.lang.Object@765d55d5,java.lang.Object@2513a118,java.lang.Object@2bfb583b,java.lang.Object@73ae0257,java.lang.Object@6fc1020a,java.lang.Object@5762658b
```

Is there a possible way to print this data values instead of object addresses.

Comment: What is `userDS` type? Seems like your falling back to `Object`s `toString` method

Comment: It's `DataSet[Row]`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Table API and Datastream API in a weird fashion. It would be best to stick to one API or use the [proper conversion methods](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/common.html#integration-with-datastream-and-dataset-api).

As is you are basically not letting Flink know the expected input/output schema. `classOf[Row]` is everything and nothing.

To write a table to Avro file, please use the [table connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/connect.html#apache-avro-format). Basic sketch

```
tableEnv.connect(new FileSystem("/path/to/file"))
    .withFormat(new Avro().avroSchema("...")) // <- Adjust
    .withSchema(schema)
    .createTemporaryTable("AvroSinkTable")
table.insertInto("AvroSinkTable")
```

---

edit: as of now, Filesystem connector unfortunately does not support Avro.

So there is no option but to use dataset API. I recommend to use [avrohugger](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avrohugger) to generate an appropriate scala class for your avro schema.

```
// convert to your scala class
val dsTuple: DataSet[User] = tableEnv.toDataSet[User](table)
// write out
val avroOutputFormat = new AvroOutputFormat<>(User.class)
avroOutputFormat.setCodec(Codec.SNAPPY)
avroOutputFormat.setSchema(User.SCHEMA$)
specificUser.write(avroOutputFormat, outputPath1)
```

Comment: I'm done with the code. But now I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.BatchTableSourceFactory' in
the classpath.
Reason: No context matches.` @Arvid